# Spring Vault SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-httpcomponents, spring-vault

I have an application running in Spring Boot, using Spring Vault to retrieve passwords. It is using KubernetesAuthentication to log in. 
This worked well until I upgraded to Spring Boot 2.2.5. I then started to get SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException:
    I/O error on POST request for "https://vault.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login"
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: 
    Certificate for <vault.vault.svc.cluster.local> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [vault.vault, vault.vault-lite, vault.vault-ha, vault.vault-dev, vault.vault.svc.cluster.local, 127.0.0.1]
```

With the dependencies below, everything works:

```
spring-vault-core: 2.2.2.RELEASE
org.springframework.web: 5.2.3.RELEASE
httpcomponents.httplient: 4.5.10
```

Updating to below, it starts failing:

```
spring-vault-core: 2.2.2.RELEASE
org.springframework.web: 5.2.4.RELEASE
httpcomponents.httplient: 4.5.11
```

I can make it work by providing a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` instead of using the default.

Creating the Vault RestTemplate like this causes the `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`:

```
VaultClients.createRestTemplate(vaultEndpointProvider(vaultEndpoint),
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Creating RestTemplate like this works:

```
VaultClients.createRestTemplate(vaultEndpointProvider(vaultEndpoint),
            new CustomRequestFactory()) //extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory
```

The question is why does the update in Spring/HttpClient cause the certificate validation to fail. The certificate seems valid since the host I am connecting to is in the SAN of the certificate.

**Update**
The problem seems to be with httpcomponents.httplient `4.5.11`. I can get it working by using the latest version of `Spring-Vault`, `Spring`, `Spring-Boot` and using `httpcomponents.httplient` `4.5.10` or `4.5.12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug introduced in `HttpClient` version `4.5.11`. Fixed in `4.5.12`

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2047